# How does React detect when a JSX node should have a key prop? How does it detect which JSX nodes are root nodes within an iterative block (map, etc.)?

Tags: reactjs, list, loops, key, jsx

The following error message appears in the console for JSX nodes at the root of iterative blocks (map, foreach, etc.): *Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.*

The aforementioned error message expectedly appears in the following case, using map (taken from React's docs):

```
const people = [
  'Creola Katherine Johnson: mathematician',
  'Mario José Molina-Pasquel Henríquez: chemist',
  'Mohammad Abdus Salam: physicist',
  'Percy Lavon Julian: chemist',
  'Subrahmanyan Chandrasekhar: astrophysicist'
];

export default function List() {
  const listItems = people.map(person =>
    <li>{person}</li>
  );
  return <ul>{listItems}</ul>;
}
```

It also expectedly appears in this modified version (using foreach):

```
const people = [
  'Creola Katherine Johnson: mathematician',
  'Mario José Molina-Pasquel Henríquez: chemist',
  'Mohammad Abdus Salam: physicist',
  'Percy Lavon Julian: chemist',
  'Subrahmanyan Chandrasekhar: astrophysicist'
];

export default function List() {
  const listItems = [];
  people.forEach(person =>{
    listItems.push(<li>{person}</li>);
  });
  return <ul>{listItems}</ul>;
```

**My question is:** How does React detect which JSX nodes should have a "key" prop? To be clear, I'm not asking about under what circumstances a JSX node needs a key or even why it's important; I wish to understand the manner in which the detection works in the first place. How does React *know* when a JSX node is a root node within an iterative block?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The key prop in React helps keep track of individual elements in a list when they are added, updated, or removed. When rendering elements inside a loop or iteration, the parent element representing the loop is considered the root node. React looks at the code structure to figure out if an element is being rendered within an iteration. If it detects that an element is part of an iteration, it assumes it's a list item and needs a unique key prop.

However, if you're using a custom way to iterate or a different data structure, React may not automatically recognise it as an iteration and won't remind you to use key props.

Make sure to assign a key prop manually in such cases to ensure efficient tracking and updating of list elements.